# Form submits only on the second Click. (only partially on first)

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a PP BUY-IT-NOW button, which I'm using to perform 2 submits.

1)  PayPal sandbox - buy  (with a custom = "randnum"  var)

2)  My PHP file that submits the user info into my DB, along with same randnum

Later they will communicate, verify, etc..

I used $.post (that I learned on here) to submit the second Submit Action.

It works only if I click buy it now the 2nd time

the first click, it goes to Paypal no problem, but, doesn't run the PHP file, which has my db input on it.

but, if I go BACK, and hit BUY IT NOW again, it works.. and works there after.

If I refresh, I need to click it once, no work, go back, and then no problem.

HELP!!!!   I've spent

```
<div id="paypal_corp">    <!--  BUY IT NOW - AND - send to DB   (corp_paypal_db_prep.php)   -->
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="corp_pp_buy" id="corp_pp_buy">        
        <input type="hidden" name="emp_email" id="corp_p_emp_email" />        
        <input type="hidden" name="empr_name" id="corp_p_empr_add_name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="empr_street" id="corp_p_empr_add_street"  />
        <input type="hidden" name="empr_city" id="corp_p_empr_add_city" />
        <input type="hidden" name="empr_state" id="corp_p_empr_add_state" />
        <input type="hidden" name="empr_zip" id="corp_p_empr_add_zip"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_rout_num" id="corp_p_rout_num" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_acc_num" id="corp_p_acc_num" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_id" id="corp_p_emp_id3"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_f_name" id="corp_p_emp_f_name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_l_name" id="corp_p_emp_l_name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_street" id="corp_p_emp_street" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_city" id="corp_p_emp_city" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_state" id="corp_p_emp_state" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_zip" id="corp_p_emp_zip" />                  
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_ssn" id="corp_p_emp_ssn" />             

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_start_date" id="corp_p_start_date" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_end_date" id="corp_p_end_date" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_pay_date" id="corp_p_pay_date" />

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_gross_hrs" id="corp_p_gross_hrs" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_gross_rate" id="corp_p_gross_rate" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_ot_hrs" id="corp_p_ot_hrs" />

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_gross_ytd" id="corp_p_gross_prd" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_gross_ytd" id="corp_p_gross_ytd" />

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_taxable_gross_prd" id="corp_p_taxable_gross_prd" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_taxable_gross_ytd" id="corp_p_taxable_gross_ytd" />

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_fed_amt_deduct_period" id="corp_p_fed_amt_deduct_period" />                    
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_fed_amt_deduct_ytd" id="corp_p_fed_amt_deduct_ytd" />

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_medicare_period" id="corp_p_medicare_period" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_medicare_ytd" id="corp_p_medicare_ytd" />

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_state_amtincomtax" id="corp_p_state_amtincomtax" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_state_amtincomtaxytd" id="corp_p_state_amtincomtaxytd" />

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_fica_social_period" id="corp_p_fica_social_period" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_fica_social_ytd" id="corp_p_fica_social_ytd" />

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_net_pay_period" id="corp_p_net_pay_period" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_net_pay_period_deposit" id="corp_p_net_pay_period_deposit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_net_pay_ytd" id="corp_p_net_pay_ytd" />

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_state_abb" id="corp_p_state_abb" />                                                                         

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_val_401k_prd" id="corp_p_val_401k_prd" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_val_401k_ytd" id="corp_p_val_401k_ytd" />

        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_commission" id="corp_p_commission" />
        <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_commission_ytd" id="corp_p_commission_ytd" />

      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="PJTU3F2LGZNXU">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.paycheckstubonline.com/testing-2" />            <!-- need to create a SUCCESS PAGE(dl/email/return)  -->
      <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.paycheckstubonline.com/listener.php" />     <!-- IPN - find and update record to pay-->
      <input type="hidden" id="custom" name="custom" />
      <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" id="submit_db_btn" border="0" name="submit_db_btn" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> 
  </form>
```

And right below it, in the same page, i have the Javascript..  (I learned the hardway, that If the Javascript was above it, it doesn't work..)

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var randomnumber = 0;
      $("#submit_db_btn").on("click",function() {
               $.post("corp_paypal_db_prep.php", $("#corp_pp_buy").serialize());  
              set_custom_var();
      });

      function set_custom_var() {
        randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000000);                                        
        document.getElementById("custom").value = randomnumber;
      }
      </script>
```

I've put an ALERT under the $.POST  and it pops up on the first click..  but, it still doesn't run the PHP file, until I click it the second time

Comment: The first time you send, do you want to send the "custom" random variable to your php script?
You are setting the randnum value only after sending the request to php here.

Comment: Yes, I want the rand sent everytime the submit button is clicked.  but, it seems to be working ok.   The PHP file is just not sending on the first click.

Comment: Well, I've tried the FULL VERSION, not the shorthand Jquery will solve this problem..  No idea why.       $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      url: "corp_paypal_db_prep.php",
      data: $("#corp_pp_buy").serialize(),
      success: function(data, status, xhr){
        alert('ok');
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        alert(status + ": " + err);
      }

Answer (score 0):

the NON shorthand verstion of Jquery call works..

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  url: "corp_paypal_db_prep.php",
  data: $("#corp_pp_buy").serialize(),
  success: function(data, status, xhr){
    alert('ok');
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    alert(status + ": " + err);
  }
```